# Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined. installation problem in laravel bootstrap-vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I have a laravel project and I add **bootstrap-vue** packages I follow the instruction how to setup https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/ and then have an error I was using is "vue": "^2.6.10", and for the bootstrap vue is v2.0.0-rc.17

My webpack.mix.js here's the code

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

This error shows up in the console.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined
>       at Object../node_modules/bootstrap-vue/es/components/button/button-close.js
>   (app.js:2924)
>       at **webpack_require** (app.js:20)
>       at Object../node_modules/bootstrap-vue/es/components/alert/alert.js
>   (app.js:2035)
>       at **webpack_require** (app.js:20)
>       at Object../node_modules/bootstrap-vue/es/components/alert/index.js
>   (app.js:2264)
>       at **webpack_require** (app.js:20)
>       at Object../node_modules/bootstrap-vue/es/components/index.js (app.js:8771)
>       at **webpack_require** (app.js:20)
>       at Object../node_modules/bootstrap-vue/es/index.js (app.js:18932)
>       at **webpack_require** (app.js:20)

Comment: Not enough information. Please, include versions of used packages, at least

Comment: I have the same problem after an npm update - 
"vue": "^2.6.10"
"bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.0-rc.17"

Comment: I just follow the basic instruction using this npm i vue bootstrap-vue bootstrap after the installation in the inspect element and check the console the error appear my version I was using is "vue": "^2.6.10", and for the bootstrap vue is v2.0.0-rc.17

Comment: Show your webpack config, please (add to question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like [this is a bug](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/3038), rollback to `2.0.0-rc.16` should fix that issue.

Comment: Its working thank you but hopefully the version 2.0.0-rc.17 will fix soon

Comment: @MindMaze And I hope we'll have _not_ **-rc** soon :)